# How launch a web service request from a string sroring this request in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I have to code multiple Web Services calls.
For this, i use requests (`import requests`).

Each call has the same structure:

```
try:
retrieved_response = requests.get(url_call,
                                      auth=authentication,
                                      params=search_parameters,
                                      verify=False)
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as http_error:
    logger.error("Bad Status Code", http_error.response)
    raise http_error
except [requests.exceptions.ConnectionError, requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout] as connection_error:
    logger.error("Connection Problem ", connection_error.response)
    raise connection_error
except requests.exceptions.Timeout as timeout_error:
    logger.error("Time Out Exception ", timeout_error.response)
    raise timeout_error
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as error:
    logger.error("Request Error ", error.response)
    raise error
```

**I want to create a generic function (or class method) that:**
**- takes as argument the request (get, post, etc) as a string**
**- executes this request passed as a simple string**
**- and returns the web service response**

Like this:

```
def generic_call(call_request: str):
    call of the web service by launching the corresponding call request
    return the json response of the web service
```

Outside of this function, i just have to prepare a string storing my request call, and pass this string as parameter to this new generic function.

**Until now, i do not know how launch a request from a string.
Could you please indicate me how launch a request from a string (a string that will store my request) ?**

Thank you very much in advance,
Thomas

Comment: What do you mean by 'launch a request from a string'?

Comment: Thank you ewokx. I want a string that stores literraly my request (for example, req = "request.call(web_service_url, auth=HTTPAuth(xxx,xxx), params={"login":"toto"})", and pass this string as parameter to a function dedicated to launch the request stored in the string.

Comment: What is the format of the `call_request` string? If it is the raw HTTP request, you'll want to use a different library like `sockets`.

Comment: Thanks Gaberocksall. For the moment, i use the simple request library to launch my request and each request has the same structure. But as i understand thanks to you, it is not possible, with requests library, to store the call request as string and launch it. I have to use sockets library to achieve my goal ? Thanls Gaberocksall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question and comments, I'm going to assume that you essentially just want to create a wrapper function that will execute the code that you give it and return the result.

You can do this a couple ways, the easiest (and not very safe) being to simply use eval

```py
req = eval("request.call(web_service_url, auth=HTTPAuth(xxx,xxx), params={\"login\":\"toto\"})")
```

Wrap this into a function like:

```
def generic_call(requestString):
    return eval(requestString)
```

If you want a safer way, you could use if statements within a function and pass in arguments from outside like this:

```
def generic_call(method, **kwargs):
    if method=="GET":
        requests.get(...)
    elif method=="POST":
        requests.post(...)
```

Your question is worded a little weirdly, but I assume you meant the eval route. I would advise you put in the extra effort to create the if-elif function, especially if you are using user input into any of these arguments.

Comment: Thanks a lot Eriall. I will use the safe method. You give me a good idea. With the eval (what i wanted) is not safe and complicated to read. Instead of method as parameter, maybe i will use an enum indicating the request to launch because i have many get requests. In fact, initially, i wanted to avoid the repetition of the structure call with the except. Thank you very much Eriall.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid using eval, you could potentially use the [PreparedRequest](https://tedboy.github.io/requests/adv3.html) object with the pickle module. PreparedRequest objects are "immutable", and pickling them will result in a "bytes" object.

```
from requests import Request, PreparedRequest, Session
import pickle

pr: PreparedRequest = Request("https://myip.wtf/json").prepare()
pickled_request = pickle.dumps(pr)
# Store the pickled request wherever you want
unpickled_request = pickle.loads(pickled_request)
session = Session()
response = session.send(unpickled_request)
return response.json()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Michiu. Very interesting solution too. I add + 1 for your solution comment.